# Como resolvo o erro "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in"?

Tags: php, javascript, html

tenho um painel administrativo e na pagina de editar o usuário recebo os dados pelo formulario e faço o update na tabela so que sempre retorna a mensagem de

> erro Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\sondplay\admin\processa\proc_edit_usuario.php on line 25

no meu `if` eu verifico se houve alguma alteração na linhas e caso houve exibe a mensagem que o usuario foi modificado e redireciona para pagina lista usuarios e caso contrario exibe a mensagem que o usuário não foi editado com sucesso o erro acho que esta no `rowCount` meu código

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../seguranca.php");
include_once("../conexao.php");
$id = $_POST["id"];
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];
$nivel_de_acesso = $_POST["nivel_de_acesso"];

/* Delete all rows from the FRUIT table */
$del = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE usuarios set nome ='$nome', email = '$email', login = '$usuario', senha = '$senha', nivel_acesso_id = '$nivel_de_acesso', modified = NOW() WHERE id='$id'");
$del->execute();
$count = $del->rowCount();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        if ($count->rowCount > 0) {
            echo "
                <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=../administrativo.php?link=2'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Usuário editado com Sucesso.\");
                </script>
            ";
        } else {
            echo "

                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Usuário não foi editado com Sucesso.\");
                </script>
            ";
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variável `$count` é um valor do tipo inteiro, não um objeto para você chamar `$count->rowCount`.

Não use

```
if ($count->rowCount > 0) {
```

Use

```
if ($count > 0)
```

Comment: agora entendi deu certinho obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Tenta chamar o $del->rowCount no if, ao invés de atribuir a uma variável, o erro está nisso.

```
$count = $del->rowCount();// tirei isto

if ($del->rowCount() > 0) {
```

Comment: eu fiz do jeito que voce disse e continua com a mesma mensagem

Comment: Dá erro em que linha ?