# MYSQLI - Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function sql_update_views ($table = null, $id = null) {
    $database = open_database();
    $found = null;
    try {
        $sql = "UPDATE ".$table." SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = ".$id;
        $result = $database -> query($sql);
        if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
            $found = $result -> fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = $e -> GetMessage();
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
    }
    close_database($database);
    return $found;
}
```

Recebo o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\armazemdahouse\include\database.php on line 167

Se aplico a solução contida na pergunta:

[Solução proposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192862/como-resolvo-o-erro-notice-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in)

Recebo o erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: num_rows in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\armazemdahouse\include\database.php on line 167

Qual a solução?

Percebi que se o usuário acessar a página e ficar apertando o F5 em seguida as visualizações da publicação vão aumentar de forma não cordial. Onde eu devo fazer o tratamento para que seja bloqueado esse tipo de situação, por IP em um outra tabela?

Comment: Leia isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5510/132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está recebendo esse erro porquê você está tentando chamar a função `num_rows()` em cima de uma consulta `UPDATE`.

Se você quer recuperar a quantidade de linhas que foram atualizadas com o `UPDATE`, utilize `affected_rows()`.

Adendo: você somente conseguirá executar esse trecho de código `$result -> fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` se na variável $result estiver armazenado um `objeto` ou um `array` de uma consulta `SELECT` ao banco de dados. Não há como você "recuperar dados" a partir de um `UPDATE`.

E de acordo com a [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/):

> mysqli_affected_rows() retorna o número de linhas afetadas pela ultima
>   consulta INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE ou DELETE associada ao parâmetro link
>   indicado. Se a ultima consulta foi invalida, esta função irá retornar
>   -1.
>
> The behaviour of mysqli_num_rows() depends on whether buffered or
>   unbuffered result sets are being used. For unbuffered result sets,
>   mysqli_num_rows() will not return the correct number of rows until all
>   the rows in the result have been retrieved.

---

Como sugerido por nosso colega, aí vai uma pequena-melhor implementação do seu código.

Observação: há inúmeras coisas que poderiam ser modificadas, porém irei manter sua lógica e conhecimento escrito no código.

```
try {
    $sql   = "UPDATE " . $table . " SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = " . $id;
    $query = $database->query($sql);

    // Retorno rápido.
    if ( ! $query) {
        throw new Exception("Oh my god, um erro."); 
    }

    $updatedRows = $query->affected_rows(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if ($updatedRows == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Nenhuma row foi atualizada.");           
    }

    // Retorna a quantidade de *rows* atualizadas.
    return $updatedRows;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
}
```

Comment: Faz umas recomendações para ele na sua resposta: não usar espaço entre o objeto, `->` e o método ou propriedade; usar `getMessage()` e não `GetMessage()`; e, por fim, testar a execução da *query* com `if ($result === TRUE)` ou `if($result)`.

Comment: @TonyMontana Tà lá ;)

Comment: Sua resposta já estava muito boa, mas obrigado por seguir minha recomendação. Eu já havia votado na sua resposta.

Comment: @GodfreytheKing obrigado pela ajuda, vou implementar aqui. vc poderia mostrar quais as mudaças que eu poderia fazer no meu código para torna-lo mais correto ou seguro ou funcional, por favor?